# What't the meaning of self.object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Object-oriented programming and I am having trouble with the parameter of "self".

Here is my code for analysing text.

```
class analysedText(object):
    
    def __init__ (self, text):
        formatted_text=text.replace(".","").replace("!","").replace(",","").replace("?","")
        lower_text=formatted_text.lower()
        self.fmtText=lower_text
    
    def freqAll(self):
        word_list=self.fmtText.split(' ')
        dic={}
        for i in set(word_list):
            dic[i]=word_list.count(i)
        
        return dic
            
    def freqOf(self,word):
        freqDict=self.freqAll()
        
        if word in freqDict:
            return freqDict[word]
        else:
            return 0
```

I just learned that self refers to instance of the class. However, I can't understand the meaning of `self.fmtText` and `self.freqAll()`. Can anyone give me a specific explanation, please?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Comment: `self.fmtText` get the `fmtText` from object `self`. `self.freqAll()` calls method `freqAll()` on object `self`. You may read more tutorial on OOP because that's the very basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` represents the instance of the class. By using the `“self”` keyword we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python. It binds the attributes with the given arguments.

`self.fmtText` is used to access the class variable and `self.freqAll()` calls the instance method `freqAll()`.